# Do you have to start from scratch for tag-specific hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I'm the third highest scoring person for [zelda-skyward-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-skyward-sword) in both Questions and Answers.  Do I have to start over to earn my Zelda hat?

(Also, no [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) hat, despite TF2 just having a major update yesterday and being "America's #1 War-themed Hat Simulator"?

Comment: Three upvotes suffice.

Comment: So, I essentially need 3 more upvotes?

Comment: I think the three upvotes need to be on a new post, but that might not be the case.

Comment: I just received 5 upvotes on 5 different answers within the same tag I've posted earlier.  It looks like it has to be new posts.  :(

Answer (score 3):

The past is forgotten
The future is close.
Your old posts are rotten
Forget about those!

Answers, you've loads,
Go posting much more!
With just a few votes,
You'll see hats galore.

Comment: and about the lack of TF2 hat? :D